# Java-Scanner locale of Germany returns 0 while summing up double values

Tags: java

this is a small program using Java Scanner which reads a file of double values and sum it up.

I was verifying using certain locale's, and for German\Germany the value is zero.

Here is the code snippet,

```
s= new Scanner((Readable) new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ScanNum")));
s.useLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
System.out.println(s.locale());
while(s.hasNextDouble())
{
sum+=s.nextDouble();
}
```

and the file which holds double values,
8.5
32,767
3.14159
1,000,000.1

other locales the value returned is1032778.74159.

Pls advise,
Thanks!!

Comment: In Germany `.` is thousands delimiter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

8.5 isn't a valid `double` value in the German locale, basically. German (and many other European locales) uses `,` as a decimal separator, and `.` as a thousands separator. So in German, your text file would have to look like this:

```
8,5
32.767
3,14159
1.000.000,1
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is caused by a different number format in Germany.  In standard German locale, the thousands separator is the dot and the decimal separator is the comma - the other way around from your format in the file.  Thus, on the very first iteration of your loop, `hasNextDouble` returns false, since `8.5` is not a properly formatted decimal in German locale - it should be `8,5`.